# Consume secret inside dockerfile

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, dockerfile

Is it possible to **access machine environments inside dockerfile**? I was thinking passing the SECRET as build ARG, like so:

docker-compose:

```yaml
version: '3.5'
services:
  service:
    ...
    build:
      ...
      args:
        SECRET: ${SECRET}
    ...
```

dockerfile:

```
FROM image
ARG SECRET
RUN script-${SECRET}
```

*Note:* the container is build in kubernetes, I can not pass any arguments to the build command or perform any command at all.

*Edit 1:* It is okay to pass SECRET as ARG because this is not sensitive data. I'm using SECRETS to access micro service data, and I can only store data using secrets. Think of this as machine environment.

*Edit 2:* This was not a problem with docker but with the infrastructure that I was working with which does not allow any arguments to be passed to the docker build.

Answer (score 34):

The secrets should be used during run time and provided by execution environment.

Also everything that is executing during a container build is written down as layers and available later to anyone who is able to get access to an image. That's why it's hard to consume secrets during the build in a secure way.

In order to address this, Docker recently introduced [a special option `--secret`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx_build/#secret). To make it work, you will need the following:

1. Set environment variable `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1`
2. Use the `--secret` argument to `docker build` command

   ```bash
   DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --secret id=mysecret,src=mysecret.txt
   ```
3. Add a `syntax` comment to the very top of your Docker file

   ```
   # syntax = docker/dockerfile:1.0-experimental
   ```
4. Use the `--mount` argument to mount the secret for every `RUN` directive that needs it

   ```
   RUN --mount=type=secret,id=mysecret cat /run/secrets/mysecret
   ```

Please note that this needs [Docker version 18.09 or later](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx_build/#secret).

Comment: You need to set the environment variable `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` for this to work.

Comment: Link to the docs changed. See [docker buildx build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx_build/#secret) for more info

Comment: Note, this answer allows for secrets to be _temporarily available in the build only_.  This may be what you want, it may not. @jonas' answer allows for them to be available _during run only_.

Answer (score 2):

`ARG` is a *build time* argument. You want to keep **Secrets** *secret* and not write them in the artifacts. Keep *secrets* in external *environment variables* or in external *files*.

```
docker run -e SECRET_NAME=SECRET_VALUE
```

and in docker-compose:

```yaml
services:
  app-name:
    environment:
    - SECRET_NAME=YOUR_VALUE
```

or

```yaml
services:
  app-name:
    env_file:
    - secret-values.env
```

### Kubernetes

When you run exactly the same container image in Kubernetes, you mount the secret from a [Secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) object.

```yaml
  containers:
  - name: app-name
    image: app-image-name
    env:
      - name: SECRET_NAME
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: name-of-secret-object
            key: token
```

Comment: I can not perform the build command by my self, it is run by a micro service in kubernetes. And it is okay to pass the secret as ARG because is not sensitive data.

Comment: Why do you use a **secret** if it not is _sensitive data_ ??? You can use environment variables otherwise.

Comment: I don't have access to environment variables :/

Comment: `ARG` is not a secret, so don't write that it is a secret. If you only have Secret in your Kubernetes, you can consume them as _environment variables_. But in a dockerfile there is no thing as a "secret", only _arg_ or _env_.

Comment: Doing this is no longer best practice. Docker now features a system that properly disposes of secrets.

Comment: Isn't this a bad practice as secrets will be available as environment variables later in the container? I read here why we shouldn't use env var for storing secrets:https://diogomonica.com/2017/03/27/why-you-shouldnt-use-env-variables-for-secret-data/#:~:text=The%20twelve%2Dfactor%20app%20manifesto,pass%20it%20alongside%20your%20configs.

Comment: Note, this answer allows for secrets to be _available while running_.  This may be what you want, it may not. @slava's answer allows for them to be available _temporarily during the build only_.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [Jonas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59143768/1198379), one can even avoid explicitly setting up the environment variables values when passing them from the host OS to the docker container.

```
docker run -e SECRET_NAME
```

The above command seeds the `SECRET_NAME` environment variable - which should exist in the host OS - to the docker container.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to passing secret data as ARG if you need to access the secret during the container build; you have no (!?) alternative.

ARG values are only available for the duration of the build so you need to be able to trust the build process and that it is cleaned up appropriately at its conclusion; if a malicious actor were able to access the build process (or after the fact), it could access the secret data.

It's curious that you wish to use the secret as `script-${SECRET}` as I assumed the secret would be used to access an external service. Someone would be able to determine the script name from the resulting Docker image and this would expose your secret.

Comment: The environment used to deploy this docker can have SECRETS but not environment variables. So the intention is to consume SECRETS as if it was machine environments. This variables are consumed only during build. This may be a mistake but it seams to be the only alternative I can think of.

Comment: You can use the ARGS values to set ENV values and send those values into the running container but it assumes nobody can get something into the running container to expose the values