# Securing credentials for private PyPi in Docker

Tags: docker, pypi

I am building a Docker image and need to run pip install vs a private PyPi with credentials.
What is the best way to secure the credentials?
Using various file configuration options (pip.conf, requirements.txt, .netrc) is still a vulnerability even if I delete them because they can be recovered.
Environment variables are also visible.
What's the most secure approach?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Consume secret inside dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59143685/consume-secret-inside-dockerfile)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand that you want to provide those credentials on build time and get rid of them afterwards.

Well, the most secure way to handle this with `pip` would be by using a multi-stage build process.

First, you would declare an initial `build-image` with the file configurations and any dependency that could be needed to download/compile your desired packages; don't worry about the possibility of recovering those files, since you will only use them for the build process.

Afterwards define your final image without the build dependencies and copy only the source code you want to run from your project and the dependencies from the build image. The resultant image won't have the configuration files and it's **impossible** to recover them, since they never were there.

```
FROM python:3.10-slim as build
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential gcc

WORKDIR /usr/app
RUN python -m -venv /usr/app/venv
ENV PATH="/usr/app/venv/bin:$PATH"

[HERE YOU COPY YOUR CONFIGURATION FILES WITH CREDENTIALS]
COPY requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements

FROM python:3.10-slim
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY --from=build /usr/app/venv ./venv
[HERE YOU COPY YOUR SOURCE CODE INTO YOUR CURRENT WORKDIR]

ENV PATH="/usr/app/venv/bin:$PATH"
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "whatever.py"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Also there's a Docker BuildKit feature to pass files with secrets as a bind mount to Dockerfile without storing it in the layer.

Such a bind mount could be defined in `RUN` instruction like this

```
FROM python:slim

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=PIP_CONF_SECRET_ID,dst=/etc/pip.conf,readonly \
    pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

And on `docker build` the source value could be passed like this

```bash
docker image build --secret id=PIP_CONF_SECRET_ID,src=${PIP_CONFIG_FILE} -t my-image:latest .
```