# Cannot install private dependency from artifact registry inside docker build when pulling from Github

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-iam, google-artifact-registry

I am trying to deploy a **Cloud run application** containing a **private python package**.
The **code** from the cloudrun is hosted on **Github**, and when I push code, it triggers a **cloudbuild** that **builds the Docker**, **pushes it to the Container registry** and **creates a cloudrun** with the image.

Unfortunately, in the docker build stage. The **Docker cannot access the private python package** that is available on the artifact registry.

I have sucessfully used that package in a cloud function in the past, so I am sure the package works. I have also given the same permissions to the cloudbuild that builds the docker to cloudbuilds that buils functions using that package, and they work.

I have created this issue in the past [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72249454/cannot-install-private-dependency-from-artifact-registry-inside-docker-build), and had possible solutions using  the Json Key file of a service account with the owner permission on the project following that tutorial from the [Google Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/python/authentication#sa-key). But I would like to avoid using a key, as the **key should not be saved on Github**. I am sure this is a permission issue, but I could not figure it out.

**cloudbuild.yaml**

```yaml
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: [ 'build', '-t', 'gcr.io/${_PROJECT}/${_SERVICE_NAME}:$SHORT_SHA', '--network=cloudbuild', '.', '--progress=plain']
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.8.6-slim-buster

ENV APP_PATH=/usr/src/app
ENV PORT=8080

# Copy requirements.txt to the docker image and install packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cython 

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

# Set the WORKDIR to be the folder
RUN mkdir -p $APP_PATH

COPY / $APP_PATH

WORKDIR $APP_PATH

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --no-color
RUN pip install --extra-index-url https://us-west1-python.pkg.dev/my-project/my-package/simple/ my-package==0.2.3 # This line is where the bug occurs


# Expose port 
EXPOSE $PORT

# Use gunicorn as the entrypoint
CMD exec gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 app:app
```

The permissions I added are:

- **cloudbuild default service account** (project-number@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com): **Artifact Registry Reader**
- **service account running the cloudbuild** : **Artifact Registry Reader**
- **service account running the app**: **Artifact Registry Reader**

**The cloudbuild error:**

```sh
Step 10/12 : RUN pip install --extra-index-url https://us-west1-python.pkg.dev/my-project/my-package/simple/ my-package==0.2.3
---> Running in b2ead00ccdf4
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-west1-python.pkg.dev/muse-speech-devops/gcp-utils/simple/
User for us-west1-python.pkg.dev: [91mERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 167, in exc_logging_wrapper
status = run_func(*args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 205, in wrapper
return func(self, options, args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 340, in run
requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 94, in resolve
result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 481, in resolve
state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 348, in resolve
self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 172, in _add_to_criteria
if not criterion.candidates:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/structs.py", line 151, in __bool__
```

Comment: Can you try to install `keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth` before accessing your artifact registry index?

Comment: I tried :( same error

Comment: According to [document](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/authentication#token), You can generate a short-lived access token for a service account and then use the token for password authentication. Since the token only valid for 60 minutes, it is a safer option than a service account key.