# Mount AWS CLI credentials to DockerFile

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, aws-cli

I am trying to mount the AWS CLI credentials from my local host system to my docker container so that I can install private packages in my requirements.txt file hosted on AWS.

I can run this example:

```
docker run --rm -it -v ~/.aws:/root/.aws amazon/aws-cli s3 ls
```

in my Ubuntu terminal just fine, but I cannot figure out how to convert it to the RUN format of a DockerFile.

For example, the DockerFile equivalent of:

```
docker run --rm -it amazon/aws-cli --version
```

Is:

```
RUN aws --version
```

But I cannot figure out how to pass the `-v ~/.aws:/root/.aws` mount aspect to it.

Any help would be MUCH appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Those are apples and oranges... See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59143954/51685

Answer (score 1):

If you are not on docker 18.X as suggested by comment and if you want the AWS secrets in your docker file.

Here is the alternative approach

```
export profile="my-aws-cli-profile"
docker build --build-arg AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(aws --profile $profile configure get aws_access_key_id) --build-arg AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(aws --profile $profile configure get aws_secret_access_key) -t myaws-cli .
```

and Dockerfile

```
FROM amazon/aws-cli

ARG AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=defaultValue
ARG AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=defaultValue
ARG AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-west-2

ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
ENV AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION


RUN aws --version
RUN aws s3 ls
```

Although it's not safe to distribute your AWS keys in the docker build.

If it just required it build time, then better to unset

```
RUN aws s3 cp s3://myrepo/file .
ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=null
ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=null
```

But remember one can read the old set value still from the docker history.